# Multiple JSON API Pages into single CSV file

Tags: php, json, api, csv

Trying to get multiple pages of an API returning JSON into one CSV file. Currently it will be sufficient to set the maximum amount of pages it will loop through to 120.

This is the first request without any loop which creates a working CSV file (output.txt).

```
<?php

$pageNo = "1";      

$jsonString = file_get_contents("http://api.domain.com/apikey/? 
name1=value1&name2=value2&pageNo=$pageNo");
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$csvHeader=array();
$csvData=array();
$csvFileName = 'output.txt';
$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');
$counter=0;
foreach($jsonDecoded["result"]["items"] as $key => $value)
{
jsontocsv($value);
if($counter==0)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, ';');
    $counter++;
}
fputcsv($fp, $csvData, ';');
$csvData=array();
}
fclose($fp);

function jsontocsv($data)
{
global $csvData,$csvHeader;
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if(!is_array($value))
    {
        $csvData[]=$value;
        $csvHeader[]=$key;
    }
    else 
    {
        jsontocsv($value);
    }
}
}

?>
```

I'm guessing this should be in a while loop, with something like ++$pageNo at the end, updating the value. However all previous attempts have resulted in the file being overwritten each time and only the last page being written into the file. How can I add stuff to the CSV each time it loops? Ideally, though, each time the entire script runs (once per day), the entire CSV file will be replaced with the updated values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are opening the file in write mode, which places the pointer to the beginning of the file (`fopen($csvFileName, 'w')`), this is why it gets overridden.. try using append mode, it should place the pointer to the end.. also, if you want to create the file if it does not exist, use the plus sign like this: `fopen($csvFileName, 'a+')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, makes sense! Do you think it would be possible to combine the two, so everything is wrapped in write mode but each loop is appended?

Comment: yes, `a+` should do it. it creates the file if it does not exist, and it appends the content in each iteration. try replacing the line `$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');` with `$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'a+');`

Comment: Works fine with a+! Just put it in a while loop, while ($pageNo <= 120), noticed now that the titles for columns are created each time so will have to move that out as well and just run it once, but shouldn't be a problem. Thanks mate.